# How to test if correct layout was used in controller in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, functional-testing, rails-3-upgrade

In Rails 2 I would do

```
  def assert_layout(layout_name)
    assert_equal layout_name, @response.layout
  end
```

and:

```
 assert_layout 'layouts/layout_name'
```

This doesn't work in rails 3 anymore (undefined method `layout'). How should I change the custom assert_layout method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `assert_template 'layouts/layout_name'`

Answer (score 2):

Also I've found that if you're doing a test for nil layout you have to do the following...

```
assert_template :layout => nil
```